# Is there a module or configuration that logs PHP mail errors?

Tags: 7, emails

On shared hosting. We're having strange mail problems... mails do not get sent to various domains or are delayed. It seems to happen more in Webforms than in Notify_message actions in Rules.

Is there a way to log the PHP mail() error messages without hacking the MimeMail module? The Drupal log only shows that there was an error... nothing more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [maillog](https://www.drupal.org/project/maillog) and [Mail Logger](https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_logger). They both log all mail activity handled via drupal_mail. See what they have to offer as far as mail errors go.

Comment: I tried that... Although it seems to log notifications from Rules, it doesn't seem to log Webform e-mails (which is the issue I'm having.) Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are your webform emails leaving at all ? Have you got anything in the watchdog (recent messages page) or the server apache error log ?

Comment: Yes the dblog pages shows a very generic 'mail' error Error sending e-mail (from "Our Site,,," <... etc.) with the from and to address. But no error # or operation. I was hoping to get an actual SendMail or error#. How can I capture that?

Comment: Anything in your sendmail logs ?